# Java vs Scala Functional Interface Usage

Tags: java, scala

In Java I can do this:

```
Runnable task = () -> { System.out.println("Task is running"); };
```

But how come in Scala I can't do the same!

```
val task: Runnable = () => {println("Task is running")}
```

I get a compiler error! I am using Scala version 2.11.8.

```
type mismatch;  found   : () => Unit  required: Runnable
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: What compiler error? I don't see any compiler error with the code above. `scala> val task: Runnable = () => {System.out.println("Task is running")}` gives `task: Runnable = $$Lambda$1011/1678449328@2917b6cb`

Comment: What Scala version?

Comment: Scala uses plain `println()`, by the way

Comment: Scala version is 2.11. As commented by Raman below.. I guess 2.12 solves this. Thx.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Scala version 2.12 supports converting lambda expressions to types with a  "single abstract method" (SAM), aka "[Functional Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)", like Java 8 does. See http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types.

Earlier Scala versions are not capable of automatically converting the lambda expression to a Java functional interface / SAM type (such as `Runnable`). You are most likely using a version prior to 2.12.

The code you provided works perfectly fine in Scala 2.12.